# Find a feasible but not optimal solution to a large LP

Tags: linear-programming

I have a large linear program, which I need to solve fast. I'm willing to sacrifice optimality but not feasibility.
I have an initial feasible point x0.
Any suggestions for an algorithm?

For example, I could use the simplex algorithm (using my x0 as warm-start, although it's not necessarily bfs/vertex) to jump from vertex to vertex and stop it after 10 iterations or when the time is up.

Another example is to use a barrier method that improves the objective while staying in the feasible domain.

Again, the point is to start with a feasible solution and improve it in the time limit.

Comment: If you use the simplex algorithm you do not just jump arbitrarily from vertex to vertex. What is your time limit?

Comment: The point was that I can stop prematurely and still get a better feasible result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primal-dual algorithm may be a useful approach in this scenario. A one-sentence summary: starting from an initial feasible solution, we find an optimal direction to go in to increase the objective function until we run into a boundary, then find a new direction to go in.

Compared to the simplex method, this has more complicated iterations (each one will need several steps of the simplex method) but each iteration can yield a greater improvement. As with many other methods, we can stop early to get a feasible but not optimal solution. I think it's a good choice in this setting because:

- It makes more progress at the beginning: early iterations are faster and often produce more improvement than later ones, whereas the simplex method is more uniform.
- It takes better advantage of the initial solution, which is feasible but not a corner point.

---

Here's a slightly more detailed description.

To be consistent with notation other people use, we're going to think of the problem you *want* to solve as the "dual program", and assume it is in the form $$(D): \quad \max\{\mathbf u^{\textsf T}\mathbf b : \mathbf u^{\textsf T}A \le \mathbf c^{\textsf T}\}$$
with $\mathbf u_0$ as the initial feasible solution (and $\mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2, \dots$ as later feasible solutions).

Our goal at each iteration is to find a direction $\mathbf v$ such that for not-too-large $t > 0$, $\mathbf u_i + t \mathbf v$ is still feasible, and increases the objective function quickly. Then we will find the largest $t^*$ that preserves feasibility, and let $\mathbf u_{i+1} = \mathbf u_i + t^* \mathbf v$.

To find $\mathbf v$, we write down a smaller linear program called the "restricted dual". For this, let $J$ be the set of dual constraints that are tight at $\mathbf u_i$ (that is, $(\mathbf u_i)^{\textsf T}A_J = \mathbf c_J^{\textsf T}$). We find $\mathbf v$ by solving
$$
    (RD) : \quad \max \{ \mathbf v^{\textsf T}\mathbf b : \mathbf v^{\textsf T}A_J \le \mathbf 0^{\textsf T}, \mathbf v \le \mathbf 1\}
$$
where the constraint $\mathbf v \le \mathbf 1$ is added because we're looking for a direction, and don't care about magnitude.

The reason that these are all duals is that the dual of $(RD)$, the "restricted primal" $(RP)$, is the one we actually solve to find $\mathbf v$ (using the simplex method). This is
$$
   (RP) : \quad \min\{\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}\mathbf y : A_J \mathbf x_J + I \mathbf y = \mathbf b, \mathbf x_J \ge \mathbf 0, \mathbf y \ge \mathbf 0\}.
$$
(Note that from the optimal dictionary/tableau for $(RP)$, we can find the optimal $\mathbf v$ using the reduced costs of $\mathbf y$, since the $\mathbf y$-variables are dual to the $\mathbf v \le \mathbf 1$ constraints.)

The reason to use $(RP)$ instead of $(RD)$ is that between different iterations, the previous optimal solution $(RP)$ can be taken as a starting point for the next $(RP)$: it is still feasible, even though the set of variables changes. Intuitively, $(RP)$ can be thought of as a version of a bigger problem with constraints $A\mathbf x + I\mathbf y = \mathbf b$, but most of its variables (the ones outside $J$) are "frozen" and cannot be made positive.

---

For more resources on this topic: I learned about the primal-dual algorithm from the book *Combinatorial Optimization* by Papadimitriou and Steiglitz (it's in Chapter 5). I have some old lecture notes online about the algorithm as well, which can be found [here](https://misha.fish/archive/482-spring-2020); the direct links to three lectures' worth of notes on this topic are [1](https://misha.fish/archive/docs/482-spring-2020/lecture29.pdf), [2](https://misha.fish/archive/docs/482-spring-2020/lecture30.pdf), [3](https://misha.fish/archive/docs/482-spring-2020/lecture31.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The best approach approach to a limited approach is to collect as many extreme points and extreme directions via the Simplex method as possible through a finite amount of iterations, then given those finite amount of extreme points and directions, we can construct other feasible points with the following definition:

> We can represent $X = (x_0, \ldots, x_n)^$ as a convex combination of the extreme points of model plus a conical combination of the extreme directions of a model.

The reason for this is further explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086391/representation-of-a-point-in-terms-of-extreme-points-and-extreme-directions-in-a). However, with a collection of extreme points and directions, we can find other feasible points within the model as such:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{00} & \cdots & x_{0n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{m0} & \cdots & x_{mn}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_0 \\
\vdots \\ 
\lambda_n\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
d_{00} & \cdots & d_{0n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
d_{m0} & \cdots & d_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
l_0 
\\ 
\vdots 
\\ 
l_m 
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_0 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
X_m\end{bmatrix} $$

With $\lambda_m,l_m\in\Bbb R^+$ $\forall m$, and $x$ represents the column/row of each chosen extreme point, $d$ represents the column/row of each chosen extreme direction, and $X$ represents the values that correspond to a new feasible point in the model. [An example of this in action has been done here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473878/find-all-basic-feasible-solutions-find-optimal-solution-for-the-given-linear-p/4544672#4544672) on another LP problem.

Of course, this isn’t the only way to find interior points of a model, and thus if above isn’t your fancy, there’s the option of other [interior-point methods](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Interior-point_method_for_LP) approaches ([and more barrier methods](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/barrier.pdf)). However, collecting as much information from Simplex is your best call before moving forward with most other approaches.